# Kernel and Differential Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

I hope your day is great so far.
I have a question. I am given a Cauchy-Euler ODE
$$\big((x+2)^3\mathbf{D}^3+4(x+2)^2\mathbf{D}^2+3(x+2)\mathbf{D}+1\big)y=\frac{1}{x+2},$$
where $\mathbf{D}^n=d^n/dx^n$. Letting $e^t=x+2$ transforms this ODE, such that the coefficients are constants, giving a new ODE
$$(\mathsf{D}^3+\mathsf{D}^2+\mathsf{D}+1)y=e^{-t},$$
where $\mathsf{D}^n=d^n/dt^n$. I can't use the formula
$$\frac{1}{p(\mathsf{D})}[e^{at}]=\frac{1}{p(a)}e^{at},p(a)\neq0,$$
since $p(a)=0$. How can I find the particular solution then? I actually find that we can use
$$y_p=\frac{1}{p_{n-k}(a)}\bigg(\frac{1}{k!}t^k+\text{ker}\,\mathsf{D}^k\bigg)e^{at},$$
for this case. However, I don't understand this formula and was hoping someone could explain that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $a$ and $p$?

Comment: @kieransquared $p$ is the polynomial of $\mathsf{D}$ and $a$ is the power coefficient in $e^{at}$

Comment: Update: I already understood part of the formula, that is we first rewrite $p_n(\mathsf{D})$ by $$p_{n}(\mathsf{D})=p_{n-k}(\mathsf{D})(\mathsf{D}-a)^k.$$ So far, I already have $n=3$, $k=1$, and $a=-1$. But I still don't understand the kernel. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(\mathsf{D}^3+\mathsf{D}^2+\mathsf{D}+1)y=e^{-t}$$
$$y=\dfrac 1 {(\mathsf{D}^3+\mathsf{D}^2+\mathsf{D}+1)}e^{-t}$$
$$y=\dfrac 1 {(D+1)(D^2+1)}e^{-t}$$
$$y=\dfrac 1 {(D+1)}\dfrac 1{(D^2+1)}e^{-t}$$
You can apply the first formula since we have  $D^2+1=(-1)^2+1=2 \ne 0$:
$$y=\dfrac 12\dfrac 1 {(D+1)}e^{-t}$$
$$y=\dfrac {e^{-t}}2\dfrac 1 {D}1$$
$\dfrac 1 D$ is simly an integration:
$$y=\dfrac {te^{-t}}2$$

Comment: Hello, I have solved that using the exactly same method with yours and obtain the same answer, but I still want to understand the formula I asked above, the one with kernel. Did you understand that formula? I was hoping anyone could explain it to me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your transformed equation
$$(\mathsf{D}^3+\mathsf{D}^2+\mathsf{D}+1)y=e^{-t}$$
has $e^{-t}$ as solution to the [homogeneous part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation) of the ODE, so proper use of the [Methos of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) is trying a solution $(At+B)e^{-t}$. Substituting in the equation you will find
$$y_p=(\frac{1}{2}t+ \frac{1}{2})e^{-t}$$

Comment: Hi, Diego. I have solved the problem and have a different answer with yours, mine is $$y_p=\frac{te^-t}{2}.$$ However, I did not claim which answer is correct, but thank you for answering! I also wondering if you understand the formula above? The one with kernel.

Comment: @Hanif both answers are correct. They differ by one solution of the homogeneous part.

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you for your helps.